# Two Windows PCs on a home network cannot resolve each other's hostnames

Tags: windows, networking, router

I have two Windows 10 PC's connected to home Wi-Fi router (Technicolor MediaAccess TG589vn). PC's are not connected to any domain. These PC's can't resolve each other's hostname. Ping by IP works fine while ping by hostname fails. How to enable name resolution?

Comment: The [manual](http://www.vectorsolutions.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/170216-tehnicolor-ds-mediaaccess-tg389ac-kk.pdf) says on page 4 "DNS server & relay", so it acts as DNS server. Now you only have to find out how to register your own names... if the firmware doesn't provide for that, you probably need root access.

Comment: Of course you can also use mDNS to announce your local names; if that's easier to do because one can't get at the router, by all means do it. mDNS is a broadcast protocol in a single segment, so it doesn't need support by a single server somewhere.

Comment: @drik Should I somehow configure Windows machines mDNS to announce their names?

Answer (score 0):

For name resolving, you need to:

1. read about what DNS is?
2. setup a dns server on one of your LAN Computers. It needs to be almost always ON, so other computers in your network can talk to it.
3. Configure your router to publish your dns server address to other computers in your network (this happens when they try to connect to your network and your router tells them their IP and other stuff via DHCP protocol)

If you are one of those lucky dudes that has an OpenWRT supported router, then, no.2 can be your router itself.

Comment: With my consumer grade non-OpenWRT VDSL-modem/router, I don't have to set up any server to use computer names in my home network either. Also, no configuration needed whatsoever. With another consumer grade cable modem/router, just adding `.local` suffices.

Comment: True, and That highly depends on your router model.

Comment: I'm owner of MediaAccess TG389ac router. I was expecting that router might be DNS server, but could't find such feature.

Comment: What do you me by `[machine name].local`. Where to use such syntax?

Comment: What @JakeGould says is that, if your router supports it, you can access your local machines by their name _(shown in System Properties -> Computer Name)_. How? Just type `ping [machine name].local` in CMD or if you want to access their files type `\\[machine name].local` in your Explorer address bar. For example: `ping room-pc.local`